# Using GPS to field walk through a LiDAR scene

Tags: qgis, gps, lidar

I am doing field surveying for archaeology using Lidar. If I attached a USB GPS to my laptop would it be possible to track where I am "in real time" on the Lidar as I am field walking?

I'm wanting to use GPS to pinpoint on a pre loaded Lidar image as we field walk an area. We have found a lot of interesting things on Lidar and it would help if we could identify them on the ground individually.

Comment: question needs more information... But see: http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_gps/index.html ,and i assume that "in real time" on the lidar doesn't mean live lidar data , only gps data